# Finding strings in a dataframe with vector of strings

Tags: r, string

Good evening,

I have the following dataframe :

```
df <- data.frame(I(list(c("nugget de blé","boeuf"),"nugget de blé")))
list_dishes <- c("nugget de blé")
```

I want to identify the df's dishes in list_dishes: counting 1 when a dishes is identified.

I wrote the following algorithm but it doesn't word. Basically the algorithm identify only when "nugget the blé" is alone.

```
classification <- function(X,list){
  compteur = 0
  if(length(which(X%in%list)>=1){compteur = compteur + 1}
  return(compteur)
}

results <- data.frame(apply(df, c(1,2), function(x) calcul(x,list_dishes)))
```

Can you help me please.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Given the data you've published, how is the desired output?

Comment: Tanks for your message. "nugget de blé" is present in both situation. Hence, I expect the following output :  results <- data.frame(1,1)      ;    results <- t(results)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sapply` with `grepl` from `base R`

```
df$found_dishes <- sapply(df[[1]], function(x) any(grepl(list_dishes, x)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much this is the solution =)

Comment: @pierrechiaverina in that case, you can use a nested lapply i.e `df[multiplecolumnsvec] <- lapply(df[multiplecolumnsvec], function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) any(grepl(list_dishes, y))); x})` assuming the columns are list

Comment: Thanks, but this function replaces each dish by true or false e.g ("True", "False") for the string ( "nugget de blé","boeuf") while I want True if there is at least one True between both dishes. Have you a tips to get this result ? Thanks

Comment: @pierrechiaverina I used `any` to check if there is any TRUE/FALSE

Comment: @pierrechiaverina Sorry, it would be `lapply(df[multiplecolumnsvec], function(x) sapply(x, function(y) any(grepl(list_dishes, y))))`. What would be names of the new column names

Comment: Thanks, I used : df <- as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(df), nrow=length(unlist(df[1])))) to turn the list output into a dataframe

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using the `tidyverse` packages, here is one solution:

```
library(tidyverse)

# I added a name to the column of your data.frame
df <- data.frame(a = I(list(c("nugget de blé","boeuf"), 
                            "nugget de blé")))
list_dishes <- c("nugget de blé")

tibble(df) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(found_dishes = map(a, ~str_detect(.x, list_dishes))) %>%
  unnest(found_dishes) %>%
  filter(found_dishes == T)

#> A tibble: 2 x 3
#> a            id found_dishes
#> <I<list>> <int> <lgl>       
#>1  <chr [2]>   1 TRUE        
#>2  <chr [1]>   2 TRUE
```

Then you count the number of rows to find how many matches you found.

Comment: Thanks for your message, This is a solution but do you know whether it is possible to work from the original dataframe ? and not transforming it using tidyverse.

Comment: Otherwise, from your suggestion, how can I get a dataframe with 1 when this is true or 0 when false.

Comment: Replace the line that mutate found_dishes for `mutate(found_dishes = map(a, ~if_else(str_detect(.x, list_dishes), 1, 0)))`, then change the `filter` line accordingly.